# aws-sdk/client-ec2 DescribeInstancesCommand returns empty array when nodejs "http.Server" is running, else returns expected data

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

I'm using aws sdk for javascript and its ec2 client **'@aws-sdk/client-ec2'**.

I'm trying to list ec2 instances using `DescribeInstancesCommand`.

```js
    async getInstances(nextToken?: string) {
        logger.info("ec2.service.getInstances");
        try {
            let input: DescribeInstancesCommandInput = {};

            let command = new DescribeInstancesCommand(input);

            const instanceData = await this.client.send(command);

            return instanceData;
        } catch (err) {
            logger.error(err);
            throw err
        }
    }
```

In above code `this.client` is EC2Client properly initialized with credentials.

I've simplified its usage below in a function

```
export async function checkService() {
    const x = new Ec2Service('default');
    const instances = await x.getInstances()
    console.log('instances', instances.Reservations.length);
    return instances;
}
```

I'm using a express for API server to serve the result of this function as a response. I'm also using other services like **s3** and **iam**, but there's no problem in those services.

Running the function if  http server is listening result in an empty array from `DescribeInstancesCommand` but if the server is not listening, I get the real ec2 instance data.

**Simplified Code for server initialization**

```
import * as http from 'http'
const server = http.createServer(() => {
  console.log("[SERVER]")
});
const _server = server.listen(process.env.PORT); //Commenting this line leads to desired output
checkService()
```